# Query selector, class contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

in Javascript i'm looking to do an action if a certain button exist.
This button is :

```
<span class="btn-text">M'y emmener</span>
```

And i have written the follow but nothing is working :

```
const listfull = document.querySelector('.btn-text a[href*="m\'y emmener"]'
    if (listfull) {
        console.log("hello")
    }
```

if somebody could tell me how to get this working ;)

Comment: There is no `<a>`tag inside the span... It *might just about work* if your html actually read something like:  `<span class="btn-text"><a href="TEXTm'y emmenerTEXT"></a></span>`.

Comment: As @ne1410s said, there's no a tag inside the span, and even if there were, `M` is not the same as `m`...

Comment: And there is no `href` attribute inside the non-existant `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick for you :)

```js
let search_term = "M'y emmener";
const listfull = $("span:contains('"+search_term+"')");
    if (listfull) {
        console.log("hello")
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn-text">M'y emmener</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const listfull = document.querySelector('.btn-text a[href*="m\'y emmener"]')
    if (listfull) {
        console.log("hello")
    }
```

```html
<span class="btn-text"><a href="m'y emmener"> M'y emmener </a></span>
```

You don't currently have an `a` tag in your document firstly. Nor does it have the href you are targeting in your query selector. Above is a revised version of the code you posted with working query selector and logic.